# Hive timestamp always returns null

Tags: hive, hiveql

i am trying to create HIVE ORC table.

My approach to create ORC table is as follows :

1. I created 2 hive tables with the same structure (one OCR and second TEXTFIle).
   for example i have a EMPLOYEE_ORC and EMPLOYEE_TEXT table
2. I load data to the text table (Employee_TEXT)

   ```
   LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/hive/data/emp/emp.json' INTO TABLE COMPANY.EMPLOYEE_TEXT;
   ```
3. Copy data from EMPLOYEE_TEXT to EMPLOYEE_ORC:

   ```
   INSERT OVERWRITE  TABLE COMPANY.EMPLOYEE SELECT * FROM COMPANY.EMPLOYEE_TEXT
   ```

Problem i am having is :
the EMPLOYEE_TEXT has a  timestamp stored as String. Which i am trying to convert to timestamp for the ORC table. For some reasons i am always getting the value as null.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE  TABLE COMPANY.EMPLOYEE_TEXT
SELECT 
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(Date_Time_Stamp, 'yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS')),
NAME 
FROM
COMPANY.EMPLOYEE_TEXT;
```

i see there is data in the hive tables but the timestamp in ORC always returns null.
Sample TimeStamp Format is : "20171109 14:37:57:026000 -0500";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i could get it to work with this function.

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20171109 14:37:57:026000 -0500','yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss:SSSSSSSSS ZZZ'))
```